# Problema con un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Es la primera vez que trabajo con procedimientos almacenados y he ido ayudandome de ejemplos que encuentro en internet.

En mi trabajo me dijeron que se necesita, por medio de un sp, mandar un correo interno. Por lo que necesito una variable de entrada que vendría a ser un número de fólio, y le creé una variable de salida que no sé cómo ocupar.

El código es el siguiente:

```
USE [RENEGOCIACION]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Sp_Scf_EnviarCorreoInterno]    Script Date: 13-04-2021 9:48:24 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- Crear el procedimiento

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_Scf_EnviarCorreoInterno] @folio_web int, @resultado varchar(40) OUTPUT

as

-- ==============================================================
-- Nombre       : Sebastián Miranda
-- Fecha        : 12-04-2021
-- Descripción  : Procedimiento Almacenado para enviar la plantilla de correo ...
-- ==============================================================

-- select a dbo.Tb_Covid19_01_Ventas
-- declarar variables
declare @id_venta int, @RutCliente varchar(12), @NombreCliente varchar(200), @ClienteCorreo varchar(200)
declare @Clientetelefono varchar(20), @Folio varchar(15), @TipoFlujo varchar(10)

select @id_venta=id_venta, @RutCliente = rutCliente, @NombreCliente=nombreCliente, @ClienteCorreo=email, @ClienteTelefono=telefono, @Folio=folio_web, @TipoFlujo = tipoFlujo from [RENEGOCIACION].[dbo].[Tb_Covid19_01_Ventas] WHERE folio_web = @folio_web


-- select a dbo.Tb_Covid19_01_Operaciones

declare @ClienteNotario int, @ClienteDeuda int, @ClienteHonorarios int

select @ClienteNotario=gastosNotario, @ClienteDeuda=montoAbono, @ClienteHonorarios=montoInteresPenal_ori from [RENEGOCIACION].[dbo].[Tb_Covid19_01_Operaciones] WHERE id_venta = @id_venta;

 
declare @Folio_a nvarchar(7), @Folio_b nvarchar(7), @Folio_c nvarchar(7)

-- selecciono los folios

select @Folio_a = folio_blq FROM dbo.Tb_Covid19_01_Bloqueos WHERE folio_web = @Folio and sCodDistribucion = 179;

select @Folio_b = folio_blq FROM dbo.Tb_Covid19_01_Bloqueos WHERE folio_web = @Folio and sCodDistribucion = 181;

select @Folio_c = folio_blq FROM dbo.Tb_Covid19_01_Bloqueos WHERE folio_web = @Folio and sCodDistribucion = 180;

-- Creación del Correo
declare @htmlBody varchar(3000)

set @htmlBody = '<body>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<p>El cliente '+@NombreCliente+', Rut '+@RutCliente+', ha avanzado en su renegociación online N° '+@Folio+' y ha realizado su abono que se detalla a continuación:</p> <br/>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<table style="border: 1px solid; width: 600px;">'
    set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<thead class="table-blue" style="background-color: #316df0; color: white; font-weight: bold;">'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
            set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<th>Ítem</th>'
            set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<th>Monto $</th>'
            set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<th>Folio Bloqueo</th>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '</tr>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '</thead>'
    set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tbody>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">Abono Deuda</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+@ClienteDeuda+'</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+@folio_a+'</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">Honorarios</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+@ClienteHonorarios+'</td>'

        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+@Folio_b+'</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">Notario</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+@ClienteNotario+'</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+@Folio_c+'</td>'
        set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
    set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '</tbody>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '</table>'


-- select para ver si viene por toc
if @TipoFlujo = 'TOC'
    begin
    set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<br/>'
    set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<p>Si cliente aún no sube documentos requeridos para renegociar, se solicita contactar con él para ayudarlo a completar esta última etapa. Los datos de contacto ingresados por el cliente son:</p>'
    end

 
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<br/><p>Si cliente aún no sube documentos requeridos para renegociar, se solicita contactar con él para ayudarlo a completar esta última etapa. Los datos de contacto ingresados por el cliente son:</p>'

set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<p>Teléfono: '+@ClienteTelefono+'</p>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<p> Correo: '+@ClienteCorreo+'</p>'

-- Envío de Correo

declare @correo varchar(100)
declare @profile_name varchar(50)

set @correo = 'smiranda.apiux@socofin.cl'; --select descripcion from [SBSOCOFIN].[dbo].[SWITCH_PORTALPAGOS] WHERE id = 57;

 

select @profile_name= name from msdb.dbo.sysmail_account;

 

declare @subject varchar(300)
set @subject  = 'Reneg Online - Pago de Abono - Rut: '+@RutCliente+' - ID Venta N°: '+@id_venta;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
 
@profile_name = @profile_name,
@from_address  ='botondepago@socofin.cl',
@body = @htmlBody,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = @correo,

-- @copy_recipients = 'nuevoliquida@socofin.cl',

@subject = @subject;
```

Para ejecutar el sp me sale esta ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde le paso el folio.

y después me sale el siguiente resultado, como en la imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que entiendo de esta última imagen es que el retorno va a ser un valor entero, pero yo nunca lo declaré.

Cuando yo ejecuto mi procedimiento por "codigo" por decirlo así, lo hace bien, pero cuando lo ejecuto como en las imagenes obtengo ese error.

Espero alguien me pueda guiar y decirme en qué estoy fallando ya que yo no entiendo mucho de procedimientos almacenados.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer aquí:. `@folio_web= N'570493',`? ¿Qué hace la `N` ahí?

Comment: no sé, por eso estoy pidiendo ayuda, esa ultimo codigo es lo que se ejecuta cuando mando ejecutar mi sp y le paso ese número de folio

Comment: quizás deba declarar la variable folio como int en vez de varchar

Comment: Depende, precisamente por eso te preguntaba. ¿Los números de folio son así: `N570493` o son así: `570493`? En el primer caso, debes dejarlo como `varchar` pero meter la `N` dentro de las comillas: **`@folio_web='N570493'`**, en caso contrario, debes declararlo como `int` y no usar la `N`: **`@folio_web=570493`**

Comment: el folio es un entero, voy a modificar el código y agregar unas capturas

Comment: El error parece vislumbrar que estás intentando convertir un asterisco en un int, por tanto, los datos tienen en algún punto un * donde crees que debería de haber un número. La N, indica que el parámetro es un tipo de dato Nvarchar (unicode) y el parámetro dice que es varchar por tanto la N sobra o falta dependiendo de lo que sea la columna `folio_web` de la tabla `Tb_Covid19_01_Operaciones`, pero el error es una conversión, y no es la del parámetro. Hay algo que no encaja, y es que el error dice algo de `valu` pero en el código no hay ninguna variable o columna que se aprecie...

Comment: @Javifer2 hola, modifiqué mi código y ahí muestro cual es mi problema real. gracias

Comment: Ya he visto que lo has resuelto, Pero aún te queda, o al menos en el código no se ve, asignar un valor al parámetro OUT para que tengas en la salida de la ejecución lo que ha ocurrido. Por otro lado, para que no tengas problemas con todos los operadores más que has puesto en el procedure. Por si te ayuda. [Concatenar cadenas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/02/02/sql-server-concatenar-cadenas/)

Comment: aaa ok, ese valor se lo puedo asignar yo manualmente, no tiene que llevar algo de la base de datos. Pero se lo voy a agregar. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

ya resolví el problema que tenía mi procedimiento.

Lo que pasaba es que al cargar las variables int o float al cuerpo del documento, que es del tipo nvarchar, tenía que convertirlas.

```
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">Abono Deuda</td>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+convert(nvarchar,@ClienteDeuda)+'</td>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid">'+convert(nvarchar,@folio_a)+'</td>'
set @htmlBody = @htmlBody + '<tr>'
```

Agregando convert() a los demás valores funciona mi sp y envía el correo.